# Reconstructing tree given only in-order traversal

Tags: tree, binary-tree, traversal, tree-traversal

Is it possible to reconstruct a tree given only the in-order traversal if the tree has, any empty children filled with an asterisk? (but is not necessarily balanced)

```
       A
     /   \
    B      F
   / \    / \
  G   *  *   * 
 / \ 
*  *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Even for simple two-node trees, there is ambiguity. Consider the output `*A*B*`. Which of these two trees produced that output?

```
       B
     /   \
    A     *
   / \
  *   *

       A
     /   \
    *     B
         / \
        *   *
```